# docker-machine shows that my ec2 docker nodes are timing out

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, devops, docker-swarm

I am experiencing this issue with my docker nodes. I have a docker swarm cluster with three nodes. I am able to SSH to each single node. However,
when I run docker-machine ls, it shows  my amazonec2 drivers state as "Timeout" even though I am able to SSH.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the [Docker Swarm documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/) it states the following ports should be opened:

- TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
- TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
- UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic

A timeout in AWS normally indicates that a security group is not allowing inbound access on the port(s) that are trying to be accessed.

Ensure you add these ports with a source of either the subnet range(s) of the other host(s) or by referencing a security group that is attached to the host(s).

Comment: Hi Chris! I have already had  those ports opened. What else do you think I could take a look at?

Comment: Are they open in your security group? I have seen TCP 2376 also being used, perhaps its that? :)